# how to remove new lines in vi editor linux?

Tags: linux

I am using Linux (centos flavor) and created a file with the following text:

```
" hello 



  world 
"
```

**Question:**

Now, I opened the file in vi editor mode and am able to remove all non blank characters(backspace or delete keys do nothing).
But newline characters persist and I get error saying "no previous regular expression".

What should I do to remove all the new lines so that my file is just empty?? I have tried backspace key many times but no effect and I do not want to use `cat > filename` to just overwrite the file to make it empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dd` to delete any lines in `vi` editor.

**Example:**
You have a file having 6 lines and you want to delete all 6 lines:

1. Open the file using 'vi` editor
2. Go to first line
3. use `6dd`

Comment: In command mode try: 2x d and then 2x . (dot) - The dot repeats last command.

Answer (score 2):

`:g` (for global) could help you here.

`:g/^$/d` basically says that "globally find any pattern matching `^$` and delete those".

If you think that you might have blanks in those lines, you could say `^\ *$`

Comment: thanks, but i think i will stick to the dd method. :D

Answer (score 0):

1. open txt with vi
2. `:1` << move cursor to first of file
3. `d` << enter delete mode
4. `G` << move cursor to end of file

It will remove all from cursor( in this case, at first of file ) to end of file

or

1. open txt with vi
2. `d`
3. `N` (Number, As many as you want to delete lines)
4. `Enter`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, could you add more detail on how each of the steps works to achieve the result?

Comment: Sorry, I add comment @WiGeeky